# Updating a single column in LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a table with multiple columns and I want to update only one column. I'm writing a method that first fetches the record and then updates it by changing the value of the column. Like this:

```
using (myDC...)
{
  var recordInDB = (from...
                    where ....
                    select r).SingleOrDefault();

  if (recordInDB != null)
  {
     recordInDB.MyColumn = newValue;

     myDC.SubmitChanges();
  }
```

Is this going to keep all the other columns as they were and only update the one I want to change or is this going to clear all columns and update the column MyColumn with the new value?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will not change the other columns in your table. Only the one you are updating.

Answer (score 4):

This is going to keep the columns that you did not touch the way they are in the database at the time of the read.

On `SubmitChanges` call LINQ2SQL compares the values in the fields of the object to the values in the database, and updates only the ones that have changed.